# How can I pass a reference to a lob variable as a parameter?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I wish to have a procedure, which gets a reference to a clob variable as a parameter. How can I modify the procedure below to reach that?

```
--here I wanna pass  sFileContent as a reference    
PROCEDURE WRITE_FILE(sPfad VARCHAR2, sFileContent CLOB) IS
    vFile utl_file.file_type;
    begin
      vFile := utl_file.fopen(logfile ,'syslog','w'); 
      utl_file.put(vFile,sFileContent); -- here I want dereference sFileContent
      utl_file.fclose(vFile); 
    end;
```

Answer (score 3):

`UTL_FILE.PUT` has the [signature](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/UTL_FILE.html#GUID-B2AA62D6-2CF8-43E2-AE64-73939F1545AD):

> ```sql
> UTL_FILE.PUT (
>   file      IN FILE_TYPE,
>   buffer    IN VARCHAR2);
> ```

You **cannot** pass a `CLOB` to it as the signature does not allow that data type as an agument. Instead you are going to need to loop through the `CLOB` and read substrings that can fit into a `VARCHAR2` data type and pass those to it.